# jQuery is not loading as module even if i define in externals section of config.json

Tags: node.js, typescript, sharepoint, spfx

I am have installed jQuery using NPM. Now I am adding this into my externals section as:

```
"externals": {
    "jQuery": {
      "path": "/node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js",
      "globalName": "jQuery1"
    }
}
```

Now I have installed unitegallery for carousel and other beautiful controls. I have installed unitegallery through NPM. I have added the dependency as below:

```
"externals": {
    "jQuery": {
        "path": "/node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js",
        "globalName": "jQuery1"
    },
    "UniteGallery": {
        "path": "/src/webparts/carouselControl/unitegallery.min.js",
        "globalName": "UniteGallery",
        "globalDependencies": ["jQuery"]    
    }
}
```

When I load them in my .ts file as `require('jQuery')` and `require('UniteGallery')`, it is gives an error as

> Resource "jQuery" not found in loader configuration of manifest for
>   component

. I am really vexed to find solution. All blogs are saying this is the only way to do. But why it is giving error to me? What I am doing wrong here?

Comment: Why are you naming the jQuery globals `jQuery1`?

Comment: I am also facing the same issue

Comment: Did you get the solution? If yes, please share am looking the solution for the same.

Comment: @ateet Please check my answer below

Answer (score 1):

With earlier version of Visual Studio code I was faced this issue. Not with latest one. Old solution is working fine now. But what I am doing from then on wards, instead of referring locally I am using [CDN](https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js) reference. First I am searching for winodw['jQuery'] object, if the object is undefined then I am loading jQuery with SPComponentLoader function. Below is sample code:

```
if(typeof(window['jQuery'])=='undefined'){
        SPComponentLoader.loadScript('https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js').then(($:any)=>{
            this.jQuery=$;
            this.initSearch();
        });
      }
      else{
        this.jQuery = window['jQuery'];
        this.initSearch();
      }
```

Comment: Am using vscode of version 1.22.2. And also referencing the libraries from cloud only. So, what i mean is that am using url https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js instead of referencing it from local.

Can i know the reason, why that way is not working?

Comment: I am not sure, but yeah ajax google api wasn't loaded for me once. I prefer CDN js. Try this it may work

Comment: I even tried that too but it doesn't work either :-(

Comment: Can you post those few lines here?